# Given $b+c=4a+6$ and $bc=5a^2+4a+5$, find $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $$b+c = 4a + 6$$

and $$bc = 5a^2 + 4a + 5$$

Find the value of each of $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: Nothing to do with sequences.

Answer (score 1):

hint: use the famous trick: $(b+c)^2 \ge 4bc \implies 4(a-1)^2 \le 0 \implies a = 1 \implies b = ...., c = ....$

Comment: I don't think that $(b+c)^2-4bc = -4(a-1)^2$. It should be $-4(a^2-8a-4)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a quadratic equation with roots $b$ and $c$. Then the sum of the roots is $b+c$ and the product of the roots is $bc$. Thus
$$(x-b)(x-c)=x^2-x(b+c)+bc =x^2-x(4a+6)+(5a^2+4a+5).$$
We want this equation to have real roots (assuming you are looking for $b,c \in \Bbb{R}$. 
Then the discriminant should be $\geq 0$.
Thus
$$(4a+6)^2-4(5a^2+4a+5) \geq 0 \implies -4a^2+32a+16 \geq 0 \implies a^2-8a-4 \leq 0.$$
This means $a \in \left(4-\sqrt{5}, 4+\sqrt{5}\right)$. Now we can say that

$$b,c = (2a+3) \pm \sqrt{-a^2+8a+4}.$$

**NOTE:** $a$ does not have a unique value. For example we can have $a=0$, in which case $b+c=6$ and $bc=5$. This yields $b=1,c=5$ or vice versa. Likewise we can have $a=1$, then $b+c=10$  and $bc=14$. This will yield $b=5 + \sqrt{11}$ and $c=5-\sqrt{11}$.